# Best practice for handling Laravel response errors with Axios

Tags: javascript, laravel, error-handling, axios, httpresponse

I have been stuck deciding which method is the best practice for error handling. This involves sending requests from Axios client side, to Laravel server side. I've got two different methods for how I could potentially handle errors. Which would be best practice and why?

For this example we will use fetching profile information from the server in **JSON** format.

**First method for error handling:**

Server side would look like this, it returns two different JSON responses dependent on whether it's a success or error. Firstly a successful response, and then an error response.

```
//success response
return response()->json([
    'success' => true,
    'data' => []
], 200);

//error response
return response()->json([
    'success' => false,
    'error' => []
], 400);
```

Client side would look like this, this sends a request through Axios to fetch profile information and handles it accordingly to the HTTP response.

```
axios.get('/json/profile')
.then((response) => {
    // handle success response (HTTP CODE 200)
})
.catch((error) => {
    // handle error response (HTTP CODE 400)
});
```

The issue with this method is that in the console you'll get messages like this: [image]

**The second method for error handling:**

This method avoids having messages like that in the console by always returning a HTTP response code of 200, with an error message if it's a failure.

The server side would look like this, the only thing that changes is the "success" value in the JSON server response.

```
//success response
return response()->json([
    'success' => true,
    'data' => []
], 200);

//error response
return response()->json([
    'success' => false,
    'error' => []
], 200);
```

The client side would look like this, it'll check the success part of the response whether it's true or false to determine whether it's an error or not.

```
axios.get('/json/profile')
.then((response) => {
    if (response.success) {
        //handle success
    } else {
        //handle error
    }
});
```

Using the second method avoids any error information been passed into the users console.

Comment: I think first method is correct because we should send the actual response code when dealing with api. Also the error in the console doesnt matter that much.

Comment: Prefer the first method, error means error, send correct status code, not 200. It doesn't matter that it's logged in console (only if opened obviously). Don't worry about this.

Comment: If there's an unambiguous HTTP response code that describes what went wrong then you should use that. Indicating an error through a successful response and a flag that requires the client to have special knowledge on the response is bad practice.